# WOT-add-on with Tor browser bundle

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, plugin

I´m using Tor browser bundle (v. 3.5).
As I see there are four add-ons preinstalled: HTTPS-Everywhere, NoScript, and of course
Torbutton and TorLauncher.
I also understand that one shouldn´t install any further add-ons as they might pose a risk as far as anonymity is concerned.
However I´d very much like to install the WOT-add-on as it provides some really good information about security of websites.
Does anybody know whether it is safe to use this particular add-on?

Comment: The NDR (a German TV station) disclosed that [WOT Services sells the complete browser history](https://thehackernews.com/2016/11/web-of-trust-addon.html) and additional data ([the technical information (German)](https://www.kuketz-blog.de/wot-addon-wie-ein-browser-addon-seine-nutzer-ausspaeht/)) of its users without any anonymisation, although they claim in their [privacy policy](https://www.mywot.com/en/privacy/privacy_policy) to "just" collect and sell anonymised information. -- **so MyWOT should neither be installed within normal browsers nor in TBB!**